# Python code printing only one row in csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Recently I've tried to code a yp.com list scraper. But could not figure out why the code is printing only one row in the .csv file.

*yp_urls.txt* urls are:

https://www.yellowpages.com/search-map?search_terms=restaurant&geo_location_terms=Boston
https://www.yellowpages.com/search-map?search_terms=restaurant&geo_location_terms=Boston&page=2

Here is the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
with open('yp_urls.txt', 'r') as f:
    for url in f:
        print(url)        
        uClient = urlopen(url)
        page_html = uClient.read()        
        uClient.close()
        page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
        containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"v-card"})
        #container= containers[0]
        out_filename = "yp_listing.csv"
        headers = "URL \n"
        f = open(out_filename, "w")
f.write(headers)
for container in containers:
            business = container.a["href"].title()
print("business:" + business + "\n" )
f.write(business + "," + "\n")
f.close()  # Close the file
```

Comment: Please include the output for your code, along with the desired output. Also include any error messages you may have received

Comment: The basic problem is you have code which I suspect you intend to be within the for loop but is not since its not properly indented.

Comment: Can you provide all or part of the yp_urls.txt  file so we can try your code.  Your link for yp_urls.txt urls is not to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues:

1. Code for your if blocks wasn't properly indented.
2. Open output file handle outside the for loop.

Try:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

out_filename = "yp_listing.csv"
with open('yp_urls.txt', 'r') as f, open(out_filename, "w") as fout:
    headers = "URL \n"
    fout.write(headers)

    for url in f:
        print(url)        
        uClient = urlopen(url)
        page_html = uClient.read()        
        uClient.close()
        page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
        containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"v-card"})
        #container= containers[0]
        for container in containers:
            business = container.a["href"].title()
            print("business:" + business + "\n" )
            fout.write(business + "," + "\n")
#f.close()  # Close the file (closed by with)
```

Comment: Your edit maintained the reference to "if blocks" but there aren't any

Comment: @JoshPilkington--I don't understand.  What if blocks?

Comment: It's still printing only one row. Please help.

Comment: @DarrylG Thank you so much for your help. It's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the f.write commands are outside of your loops, so are only being hit once the loops are completed.

For example, the code loops through the urls, then exits the loop and executes f.write(headers), then loops through containers, exits that loop and f.write(business:..)

You may also wish to check if the output file is being opened in right state with 'w' (write/overwrite) versus 'a' (append).   Perhaps also consider changing the handles so both are not 'f'.